# I am getting an error on .addFirst method, why?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ConverAryToList {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] stuff = { "people ", "watermelon ", "melons ", "fudge " };
        List<String> list = new java.util.LinkedList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(stuff)); 


        list.add("pumpkin"); 
        list.addFirst("first"); 

        stuff = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); 

        for (String x : stuff)
            System.out.printf("%s", x);

    }

}
```

This is a simple exercise on adding elements to a list. On **list.addFirst** I get: *The method addFirst(String) is undefined for the type List*. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What do you think the error means? What could it possibly mean?

Comment: How come the method .add is defined, and addFirst isn't? This might  not be an advanced question, but I'm missing something here, I really don't have an idea.

Comment: You're making assumptions. Don't do that. Refer to the javadoc.

Comment: Based on RobF's answer, why don't you use an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference type is the `List<T>` interface, which does not declare any `addFirst` method.

You can either set the reference type explicitly as `LinkedList<String>`:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(stuff));
```

Or you can cast:

```
((LinkedList<String>)list).addFirst("first");
```

The first methodology is preferred.

Casting is slightly more "dangerous", because it assumes your reference has not been assigned a new value.

For instance, if you assigned `list` to `new ArrayList<String>();` in between the two statements above, you'd get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: If do as you say, I get a The type LinkedList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String> on the LinkedList type.

Comment: @nosille that doesn't make sense. Check your imports. `java.util.LinkedList` **is** a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

method `addFirst` exists on class `LinkedList`, not on interface `List`.

Here :

```
List<String> list = //whatever
```

`list` is considered as a `List`, not a `LinkedList`

Change it to :

```
LinkedList<String> list = //whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` implement two interfaces: `List` And `Deque`.
Method `addFirst` is declared in `Deque` interface.

```
Deque list = new LinkedList<Number>();
list.addFirst(3);
```